# Where are user-defined usage messages stored in the front-end for autocomplete stored -- and how can I clear them out?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete, usage-messages

I am writing some code which automatically sets the usage messages for a function, and I am having some trouble iterating on it, particularly in getting it to work correctly in the autocomplete.

At heart, it seems that the usage message can be easily removed from the kernel using `ClearAll` or `Remove`, but that the front end will tend to remember the autocomplete message even after `Quit`ting the kernel. One example:

> [image]

(I get identical behaviour with `Remove` and `Quit`. I'm running version 13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022).)

**Is it possible to do something, ideally via evaluating a cell, which will completely expunge all records the front end has of the usage message of a particular user-defined function, so that it can be redefined over a clean slate?**

Comment: Well, ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`CacheTemplateAndUsagePacket[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "foo", {}]]`` ***after*** `ClearAll[foo]` will disable(?) the template. If you assign another usage message to `foo`, then it seems you have to manually cache the new template with ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`CacheTemplateAndUsagePacket[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "foo", FE`GetTemplateAndUsage["foo"]]]``. Not ideal. I don't know if there's another way. I couldn't find a way to remove `"foo"` from the cache or clear the cache. ``?F*E*`*empl*`` is all I found.